# Share Database Sessions between cakephp 2 and cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to share sessions between two cakephp apps that are on different subdomains. One is cakephp 2 and other is cakephp 3.

What i have so far:

1. The two apps are reading sessions from the same database table.
2. The two apps are writing session cookie "CAKEPHP" to the root domain. i have a

   `ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.domain.com');` on top of core.php and app.php respectively
3. both apps have the same Security.salt value

**What is the problem?**
When i open the cakephp 2 on one tab, it generates a session cookie with one value. But when i open cakephp 3 on another tab, it generate another value for session cookie. So, when i login on cake2 and then refresh cake 3 on another tab, the session on cake2 get lost.

When researching, i saw that **cakephp** 3 encrypts the session cookie and cake2 not... But i'm not able to see where can i make cake2 use the same encryption as cake3. Or disable encryption on both, if it will not cause security issues.

Can you help me on this?

Comment: CakePHP does not encrypt session cookies, that wouldn't make any sense. For starters, do not set session ini values manually, instead use the session configuration provided by CakePHP ([**2.x docs**](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#setting-ini-directives), [**3.x docs**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#setting-ini-directives)). Then do some debugging, starting with whether the browser actually sends the session cookie it received from one domain, to the other domain.

Comment: I did something like this, but found that I had to tweak one of the Cake session classes slightly because one version saves the session expiry time and the other saves the session creation time, but they both use the same property in the session for storing it. So one of them was always expiring the existing session immediately. I don't remember the specifics of it at the moment, but the hack to fix it was straight-forward.